# Paragraphs no longer indent after caption

Tags: captions, indentation, paragraphs

[Rewritten the original post. For the later **update** see below.]

It seems that my paragraphs stop indenting due to the use of

```
\captionof{figure}
```

in the code below. Any suggestions for a workaround or fix?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newtcolorbox{abox}[2][]{float, fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, title={#2},#1}
    
\begin{abox}{title}
{body}
\end{abox}
\captionof{figure}{caption}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test 

test test test test test test 

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test 
\end{document}
```

**Update**:

Two suggestions were made; as the box shouldn't float I tried using `center`. This however causes strange spacing issues of text within the box, unless it is placed slightly differently:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox{abox}[2][]{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
                         attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, 
                         title={#2},#1}

\usepackage[unicode=true,
            pdfusetitle,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            breaklinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 1},
            backref=false,
            colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{abox}{title}
{

{\begin{enumerate}
\item testttttt 
\end{enumerate}
testttttt
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{1} 
    \item testttttt
\end{enumerate}
testttttt
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{2} 
    \item testttttt
\end{enumerate}}

}
\end{abox}
\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example makes three paragraphs all indented, add more text so [you see the indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIy9m.png)

Comment: Oops you're right! Give me a few minutes whilst I add more code to see if I can find the issue...

Comment: Is it possible you have no blank lines between `\end{abox}` and the following paragraph?

Comment: Adding a blank line there doesn't seem to fix it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Since your original question is already solved (with accepted answer), I suggest that for new problem you ask new question. Vertical distances of caption is very different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm your findings. It seems that `\captionof{...}{caption text}` should be enclosed in some environment. For example

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox{abox}[2][]{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
                         attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, 
                         title={#2},#1}

\usepackage[unicode=true,
            pdfusetitle,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            breaklinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 1},
            backref=false,
            colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{abox}{title}
{body}
\end{abox}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\end{center}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test

test test test test test test

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test
\end{document}
```

or if `abox` should float, than replace `center` with `figure`:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{abox}{title}
{body}
\end{abox}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: If `figure` is used, ordinary `\caption` will work.  (Also, you mean `center`, not `canter`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, oh apparently I woke up to early in wasn't be careful enough :-). Spelling tipo is now corrected, regarding `caption`: in example with `figure` it is used standard `\caption`, so what I should do about this?

Comment: Thanks very much. The box should not float so I tried using `center` but this causes spacing issues that I do not know how to resolve; see the updated post for an example...

Comment: @user8463, what spacing issues? Testing your edited question gives to my opinion a nice result.

Comment: @user8463 -- If the `center` environment adds too much space, you can instead wrap the box in `\begingroup \centering ... \endgroup` and adjust the spacing yourself.

Comment: I think I had already solved it by the time you (Zarko) copy-pasted the code: I moved the `\begin{center}` part to start just above the `\captionof`, as it does in the edited version of the opening post. If you move it back to where you originally placed it, it gives rather strange spacing within the box (looks like a bug I would say)