# Strange vertical spacing in tcolorbox after center

Tags: tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

This is a sequel to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679768/paragraphs-no-longer-indent-after-caption/679776) question, which was partially resolved and it was suggested there that I start a new question.

I've created a box with tcolorbox, which should not float and I want to attach a caption which should "stick" in the sense that it should be on the same page as the box.

The solution suggested by Zarko in my previous question does strange things to vertical spacing inside the box, as can be seen in the code below.

I came up with a small workaround in the previous question but the caption doesn't stick. Does anyone have any suggestions for a workaround or fix?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\newtcolorbox{abox}[2][]{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries, 
                         attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, 
                         title={#2},#1}

\usepackage[unicode=true,
            pdfusetitle,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            breaklinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 1},
            backref=false,
            colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{abox}{title}
{
{\begin{enumerate}
\item testttttt 
\end{enumerate}
testttttt
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{1} 
    \item testttttt
\end{enumerate}
testttttt
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{2} 
    \item testttttt
\end{enumerate}}
}
\end{abox}
\captionof{figure}{caption}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/237192 (`center` vs `\centering`)

Comment: Thanks that's very interesting, but it doesn't seem to make the caption stick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about certain items in your example, so I changed some of it to be able to target the lack of vertical spacing at the first `enumerate`. This code example shows the correct vertical spacing inside and outside the `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{abox}[1][]{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    nofloat,    % added to prevent tcolorbox becoming a float
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, 
    title=#1}

\usepackage{enumitem} % added to use the resume option

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to insert some random text

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
    
        \begin{abox}[title]
            top text
                \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
                        \item testttttt 
                \end{enumerate}
            
                    testttttt
            
                \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{1} 
                    \item testttttt
                \end{enumerate}
                
                    testttttt
                
                \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{2} 
                    \item testttttt
                \end{enumerate}
                    testttttt
        \end{abox}
        \captionof{figure}{caption}
    
    \medskip    
    \lipsum[2][1-2]
    
\end{document}
```

I made the following changes:

1. added the `enumitem` package, so you can use the `resume*` option in subsequent `enumerate` occurrences without having to reset the counter
2. changed the number of variables in your `abox` to just one for the title. You don't need to define a variable for the content of the box
3. removed all superfluous brackets as a result of that change
4. added the option `nofloat` to your box definition as you clearly stated you don't want the box to be a floating object
5. removed the `center` environment as that is no longer required to prevent floating
6. since the caption is following the box, but not attached to it, you need to add some vertical space to increase the distance between caption and next paragraph. You can't use the option `before / after skip balanced` from `tcolorbox` (see pages 86-88 in the manual)

The result of these changes:

[image: vertical spacing correct]

As to why the vertical spacing is altered at the first `enumerate` when embedded in a `center` environment, I have no clue.

*Edited to include options in comments*

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{abox}[1][]{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    nofloat,    % added to prevent tcolorbox becoming a float
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm}, 
    title=#1}

\usepackage{enumitem} % added to use the resume option

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to insert some random text

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
    
        \begin{abox}[title]
            caption inside a parbox
                \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
                        \item testttttt 
                \end{enumerate}
            
                    testttttt
            
                \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{1} 
                    \item testttttt
                \end{enumerate}
                
                    testttttt
                
                \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{2} 
                    \item testttttt
                \end{enumerate}
                    testttttt
        \end{abox}
        \noindent \parbox{\linewidth}{\captionof{figure}{caption}}
    
    \medskip    
    \lipsum[2][1-2]
    
    \noindent \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    
            \begin{abox}[title]
        boxed inside a minipage
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
            \item testttttt 
        \end{enumerate}
        
        testttttt
        
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{1} 
            \item testttttt
        \end{enumerate}
        
        testttttt
        
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*]%\setcounter{enumi}{2} 
            \item testttttt
        \end{enumerate}
        testttttt
    \end{abox}
    \captionof{figure}{caption}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \medskip
    \lipsum[4][4-8]
    
\end{document}
```

This code example shows the correct indention after the use of `\captionof`:

[image: tcb in minipage]

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code! The point of the "fix" in the previous question was that center is needed to make sure the text paragraphs following the boxes still indent properly. Removing it reintroduces the problem...

Comment: ... I guess I can wrap the box in a figure environment and turn that into a nofloat version with [H]. Should circumvent the issue, but maybe someone should submit a bug report somewhere...

Comment: Yes I noticed that afterwards. I use `captionof` a lot too, but never noticed this behaviour. Will start looking whether it occurs in my documents too.

Comment: Well, I found a workaround for that behaviour. When I use  `\noindent \parbox{\linewidth}{\captionof{figure}{caption}}` the next paragraph is indented correctly.

Comment: Another option is to include the box plus caption in a `minipage` environment as the manual of `caption` suggests on page 16 (refers to another situation, but still). So the code to add would be: `\noindent \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... box plus caption ... \end{minipage}`. This does not ruin vertical spacing inside the box. Added benefit: the caption is now locked to the box.